# C# MySQL - Retrieve data from specifi column and insert into variable

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to return an int value from a dataset.

```
private int AccountID()
    {var ds = new DataSet();
        var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(
                "(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1", databaseCon);
        da.Fill(ds);
        var id= ds.Tables[0].Columns[0];

        return id;
    }
```

However I cannot return id as it "Cannot convert expression".

After the int is returned I wish to insert it into a variable to be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be better served by ExecuteScalar():

```
var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id = 1", databaseCon);
int id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I've been looking for.